# turn http post request to http get

Tags: java, linux, get, http-post, get-request

I want to setup a proxy or a standalone aplication where a "server A" can do some POST request to this proxy and turn the POST request to a GET request to "server B". 
Then the GET response must be redirected to "server A" which is waiting a response for the POST.
¿Is it possible?

What I want to get from the request is a static pdf.

Any idea how to do it would be great

Thanks

Comment: Apparently, "Yes." is less than 30 characters :(

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this as the semantics are different.

GET requests are designed to be cached (i.e. usually static stuff). POST on the other hand is more dynamic and is not cached.

You are very likely to get undesired behaviour if you do this.

Comment: What I want to get from the request is a static pdf, so there is no problem. Any idea how to do it?